# Filter Salesforce CRM Analytics dashboard using query string parameter

Tags: crm-analytics

I would like to link from a `Salesforce Record` to a `Salesforce CRM Analytics Dashboard`, and filter the CRMA Dashboard by the record ID of the source Salesforce record, taken from the query string.

I know how to create links from Salesforce record, but I cannot see any documentation about CRMA having dynamic filters based on query string.

1. Is it possible?
2. If so, how do we do it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this will be by embedding the dashboard to the lightning page using *CRM Analytics Dashboard* standard component and enabling [Open Dashboard](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_embed_lightning.htm&type=5#:%7E:text=Title%20is%20selected.-,Open%20Dashboard,-Specify%20where%20the) option and setting it to Analytics Studio. This way your dashboard (or a summarized layout thereof) will be visible to the user on the record page; and when the [Dashboard Filters](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_embed_lightning.htm&type=5#:%7E:text=and%20no%20selection.-,Dashboard,-Filters) are set to filter the dataset(s) by the Record ID, the filters will be transferred to Analytics Studio automatically.

Another approach will be to creat a very minimal dashboard with pertinent KPI's or info and have it filtered by the current record; add a link widget with [Apply Selections and Filters](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_dashboard_widgets_link_add_flex.htm&type=5#:%7E:text=Apply%20Selections%20and%20Filters) turned on to transfer the [state](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_rest.meta/bi_dev_guide_rest/bi_resources_dashboard_state_rep.htm) (filtered by RecordID) to the target Dashboard.

You can also programmatically [get and set the state](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/analytics/dashboard-component/guide/bi-dbcomp-stateusecase.html) of the dashboard, if you want to develop something custom.